# Why in a function which is called of a timer the argument has other value?

Tags: c, timer, gtk

I have this piece of code:

```
int gui_createButtonStart(struct GameGUI **gameGUI)
{
    .
    .
    .
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT((*gameGUI)->buttonStart), "clicked",
                     G_CALLBACK(gui_clickStart), gameGUI);

    return 0;
}

int gui_deleteGameGUI(struct GameGUI **gameGUI)
{
    if (gameGUI == NULL || *gameGUI == NULL)
        return POINTER_NULL;

    free(*gameGUI);
    *gameGUI = NULL;

    return 0;
}

int gui_closeWhistGame(GtkWidget *windowTable, struct GameGUI **gameGUI)
{
    if (windowTable == NULL)
        return POINTER_NULL;

    gui_deleteGameGUI(gameGUI);
    gtk_widget_destroy(windowTable);
    gtk_main_quit();

    return FUNCTION_NO_ERROR;
}

int gui_clickStart(GtkWidget *button, struct GameGUI **gameGUI)
{
    if (gameGUI == NULL)
        return POINTER_NULL;
    if (*gameGUI == NULL)
        return POINTER_NULL;
    if ((*gameGUI)->game == NULL)
        return GAME_NULL;

    gtk_widget_hide(button);
    gui_startRound(gameGUI);

    return FUNCTION_NO_ERROR;
}

int gui_startRound(struct GameGUI **gameGUI)
{
    gui_startTime(gameGUI);

    return 0;
}

int gui_startTime(struct GameGUI **gameGUI)
{
    if (gameGUI == NULL)
        return POINTER_NULL;
    if (*gameGUI == NULL)
        return POINTER_NULL;
    if ((*gameGUI)->limitTimeGUI == NULL)
        return POINTER_NULL;

    guint interval = (1000 * LIMIT_TIME) / LENGTH_TIME_LINE;
    g_timeout_add(interval, (GSourceFunc)gui_timer, (gpointer)gameGUI);

    return FUNCTION_NO_ERROR;
}

gboolean gui_timer(gpointer data)
{
    struct GameGUI *gameGUI = *((struct GameGUI**)data);

    if (gameGUI == NULL)
        return FALSE;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct GameGUI *gameGUI = gui_createGameGUI();
    GtkWidget *window;
    .
    .
    .
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
                     G_CALLBACK(gui_closeWhistGame), &gameGUI);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

This code was taking from a project of mine. When I run the code, appears on screen a button. When I press on him is called gui_clickStart() and start a timer. When I press 'x' the window will be closing (but I have multiple open windows) and *gameGUI will receive NULL. The problem is that in timer *gameGUI isn't always NULL, sometimes is NULL, sometimes isn't NULL. Why?

Comment: Where is your gui_createGameGUI() method?

Comment: here: https://github.com/EnachescuAlin/WhistGame/blob/develop/src/WhistGameGUI/gui.c#L1103  You find on github all code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should kill the timeout when the window is closed.

`g_timeout_add` returns a guint32 which is the source ID. You can use that to remove the timeout in your `gui_deleteGameGUI` function. Something like

```
int gui_deleteGameGUI(struct GameGUI **gameGUI)
{
    if (gameGUI == NULL || *gameGUI == NULL)
        return POINTER_NULL;

    g_source_remove((*gameGUI)->gameTimer);
    (*gameGUI)->gameTimer = 0;

    free(*gameGUI);
    *gameGUI = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

assuming that you store it like this in your `gui_startTime` function.

```
guint interval = (1000 * LIMIT_TIME) / LENGTH_TIME_LINE;
(*gameGUI)->gameTimer = g_timeout_add(interval, (GSourceFunc)gui_timer, (gpointer)gameGUI);
```